# rdl 2005 <visibility> element not working with report viewer 2012

Tags: rdl

Is there any issue with the rdl 2005 rendering in report viewer control 2012.

I created a rdl in 2005 schema with a table inside it and set its visibility to 'False'.

I rendered it with Report Viewer 2012. On rendering table is still visible.

visibility tag is not working properly..
.rdl is getting saved correctly.